# how to order student rank on the basis of obtain marks on different subject in sql

Tags: sql, position, rank

Here is our table

```
name         math     physics     chemistry    hindi    english
pk           85       65            45          54       40
ashis        87       44            87          78       74
rohit        77       47            68          63       59
mayank       91       81            78          47       84
komal        47       51            73          61       55
```

we want to result show as (summing the grades essentially)

```
rank    name          total
1       mayank        381
2       ashis         370
3       rohit         314
4       pk            289
5       komal         287
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to SUM two fields within an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877797/how-to-sum-two-fields-within-an-sql-query)

Comment: Please show your code to get a quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @rank=0;

SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,name,(math+physics+chemistry+hindi+english) as total
FROM tablename ORDER BY total DESC
```

this will produce your desired result as

```
rank | name | total

--------------------
1    | mayank | 381
2    | ashis  | 370
```

for more details take a look [mysql ranking results](http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results)

Comment: Good answer! You can handle this in one SQL statement as I answered, just a little trick to know.

Comment: yeah,that guy seems like new to sql , so I didn't want to complicate. @name

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank, name, (math + physics + chemistry + hindi + history) AS total FROM table, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This will sum all the fields and sort them by descending order and add a rank.

By doing `SELECT @curRank := 0` you can keep it all in one SQL statement without having to do a SET first.