# Summing two fields in excel

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table

Trying to figure out best way to sum large amount of data. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877797/how-to-sum-two-fields-within-an-sql-query), but the code needs to be automated for large amount of data. I'm thinking could this be done with pivot tables?

The data is looking like this:

```
Type  | 1.1. 0:00  | 1.1. 1:00
x1    | 2          | 1
x1    | 1          | 2
x2    | 3          | 1
x2    | 1          | 1
x3    | 2          | 3
```

Result would look like this:

```
Type  | 1.1. 0:00  | 1.1. 1:00
x1    | 3          | 3
x2    | 4          | 2
x3    | 2          | 3
```

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for Pivot tables. Did you face any issues using Pivot Tables

Comment: Well I tried it but since there is something like 1000 timestamps and 1000 type stamps it's nearly impossible to do effectively. I guess using python is best shot

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a simple aggregate query:

```
SELECT type, SUM(col1) AS col1, SUM(col2) AS col2 FROM mytable GROUP BY type
```

NB: `1.1. 0:00` and `1.1. 1:00` are quite unusual column names ; you probably want to rename them to avoid the need to escape them whenever you need to access them. I renamed them to `col1` and `col2`.

Comment: Well they are time stamps, so I think it's necessary. Can this be done automated... like: SELECT type, SUM(col1) AS col1, SUM(col2) AS col2..... ..... SUM(col300) AS col 300 FROM mytable GROUP BY type

Comment: @Mr.Man: to me these are columns headings, so you should be free to change them. But anyway, that does not change the solution...

Comment: @Mr.Man: no, a SQL query cannot dynamically generate the 1..300 columns for you. You would need to use dynamic SQL, which is more complicated. However, many other tools can help generating such a string with repeating parts, eg Excel formulas can easily do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask a few clarifying questions before the formatting of your data kicked in.

I concur with GMB.