# how to run sql query for sum of two or more rows in php file

Tags: php, mysql

How to run query in php for sum of two or more column in horizintally.

suppose i have table like

```
srno   name   english  maths  science  TotalMarks
1      rohit  52       52     52           ?
```

so how to get sum of all marks. and show in total marks field. by php code.

Comment: You should normalize your database schema.

Comment: Just: `select t.*, english + maths + science total_marks from mytable t`?

Comment: Yep, that's not a table; it's a spreadsheet. :-(

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach would be somewhat as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,srno INT NOT NULL
,subject VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,mark INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,1,'english',52),
(2,1,'maths',52),
(3,1,'science',52);

SELECT srno
     , SUM(mark) total 
  FROM my_table
 GROUP 
    BY srno;
    +------+-------+
    | srno | total |
    +------+-------+
    |    1 |   156 |
    +------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT srno, name, english, maths, science, (english+maths+science) As TotalMarks FROM `table_name`
```

Check also this topic:
[How to SUM two fields within an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877797/how-to-sum-two-fields-within-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

SELECT *, (english + maths + science) AS Total FROM table;

Answer (score 0):

Well You can try these two methods:

```
select * from Your_Table_Name;
```

and when you display your result, you can add all these values like:

```
srno   name   english  maths  science  TotalMarks
$id    $name  $english $maths $science ($english+$maths+$science)
```

OR

```
select id, name, english, math, science, (english+maths+science) as Total from Your_Table_Name;
```