# BigQuery, Sum by week

Tags: google-bigquery, dayofweek

I am using standard SQL and am trying to add the weekly sum for product usage by week.

Using code below, I was able to add to each row the respective week and year it falls into. How would I go about summing the totals for an item by week and outputting it in columns, say up to the last 8 weeks.

```
extract(week from Metrics_Date) as week, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Metrics_Date) AS year
```

Image is my raw data with the week and year next to an item:

[image]

This image is of above raw data being analyzed further(grouping them together). Here is where I would want to add columns, current_week & firstday of week date, and a sum of that weeks totals. 
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to SUM two fields within an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877797/how-to-sum-two-fields-within-an-sql-query)

Comment: In image 2, I need a new column say, last week, next to Last1TotalRequests, where it SUMS the message_count from image 1, grouped by company_name, product_name for the last actual week

Comment: In order to further help you I need to check if I understood correctly, you want first to sum a column grouped per week , so each week number will have a certain SUM. Then , you want to display only last week's sum based in the current week. Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `extract()` by the way, you can do [truncation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_trunc) `DATE_TRUNC(your_date, WEEK)` and it will truncate it to the week, usually easier.

Also, because the result of the truncation is a date, you will have the first day of the week already.

The rest I believe you have it figured out already, but just in case:

`SELECT DATE_TRUNC(your_date_field, WEEK) AS week, SUM(message_count) AS total_messages FROM your_table GROUP BY 1`

Comment: thanks for telling me about DATE_Trunc. I guess I had it solved but leaving this answer for future users.